# How to sell digital and physical goods in one product in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a project for an online store where they need to offer customers the opportunity to download a physical book they've purchased.

After much googling and research I've only found ways to sell digital products separately. This is a question to WP experts here: how to combine the 2?

I'd appreciate any help even just nudging me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey from personal experience I would...

No code examples here however you could create the Books as:
1 Physical Product $15.99
1 Virtual Product $15.99

When the customer adds the Physical product to their cart you automatically add the virtual product with 100% discount (So customer only pays $15.99)

This would mean customer has access to the physical and virtual copies of their book but if they remove the physical copy in the cart it would lose the discount and still charge them $15.99

That way you have full control over how many times customers can download the book.